fastmap vs node2vec
Fastmap, when run on a graph, generates Euclidean embeddings that try their best to preserve the distance matrix of the original graph. The algorithm is very successful in doing that. It is extremely fast with complexity O(|V|).
Node2vec, on the other hand, is way slower. First, it requires computing random walks on the graph. It treats those walks as sentences. Then it applies algorithms taken from the NLP domain (CBOW). As such generating those embeddings. It aims to create embeddings that make nodes that are close in the graph, close in the embedding. And vice-versa.
Why is Fastmap not used in graph machine learning literature as much as node2vec? Both seem to try to preserve the distance matrix among the nodes. The computational efficiency of Fastmap would triumph over any marginal rewards that come with using node2vec, if they exist.
